# How to print lines between a pattern and a line starting with another pattern?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need your help in parsing a log file with AWK (preferably) in order to extract only the necessary information. I simplified it a lot to be more visible, and it looks like this:

```
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 1 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 1
LOG_TEXT 1
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS whatever:Jhon 1 + random_text
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 2 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 2
LOG_TEXT 2
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS ANYTHING 2 + random_text
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 3 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 3
LOG_TEXT 3
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 3 + random_text
```

Detailed description:

The overall idea is to only filter lines containing "name:Jhon" (without whatever:Jhon) and their corresponding LOG TEXT (which can contain anything and it is not timestamped!).

I numbered each line at the end to make the 3 groups of possible situations more visible (LOG TEXT ending in a line with "whatever:JHON" (1-line not printed); with a generic datestamped line "ANYTHING" (2 - line not printed) ; or with "name:JHON" (3 - line printed))

---

The functionality is part of a workflow in Vmware Vrealize orchestrator (so the actual language is JS but i can use ssh and awk) but i won't go deep into that.

I've tried various awk and regex patterns but couldn't figure it out.
The closest i could get is something similar to this:

```
awk '/Jhon/{flag=1}/whatever/{flag=0}flag' file.txt
```

But this is wrong since i consider "whatever" to be a fixed pattern and also, in this case the line containing "ANYTHING" is not being filtered. In reality, 'whatever' and 'anything' (as well as random_text and time HH:MM:SS) can literary be anything. So The only way to stop the matching is to stop it on lines starting with date format (but i cannot use 2019 as it is being used on each non-LOG_TEXT line).

---

Also tried with some JS regex but it is much too complicated.

The final output should look like this:

```
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 1 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 1
LOG_TEXT 1
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 2 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 2
LOG_TEXT 2
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 3 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 3
LOG_TEXT 3
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 3 + random_text
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this :

```
 awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{if($0~/name:Jhon/){flag=1}else{flag=0}}flag' file.txt
```

---

Explanations :

- a ~ /pattern/ will check if variable `a` matches `pattern`
- In your code, you used `/Jhon/{flag=1}`. This expression is just a shortcut for `$0 ~ /Jhon/{flag=1}`. Block `{flag=1}` will be executed if the line ($0) matches pattern `/John/`
- `$1 ~ /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/` means that the block will be executed if the first column of the line matches a date format `YYYY-mm-dd` (<4 digits>-<2 digits>-<2 digits>)

  ```
  awk '
      # If first column matches a date format
      $1 ~ /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{
          # If the line contains name:Jhon
          if($0~/name:Jhon/)
          {
              flag=1
          }
          else
          {
              flag=0
          }
      }
      # Prints if flag != 0
      flag
  ' file.txt
  ```

---

But of course if LOG_TEXT starts somewhere with a date it will fail.

If LOG_TEXT is always on 2 lines, you could try this :

```
awk '{counter-=1}/name:Jhon/{counter=3}counter>0' file.txt
```

Returns

```
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 1 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 1
LOG_TEXT 1
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 2 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 2
LOG_TEXT 2
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 3 + random_text
LOG_TEXT 3
LOG_TEXT 3
2019-05-22 HH:MM:SS name:Jhon 3 + random_text
```

Comment: LOG_TEXT is any random text of any number of lines. I tested your awk and it looks nice. In my case LOG_TEXT will not start with a date (because it is actually a JSON). I'll come back if I find any scenario where it doesn't work.

Comment: Would you mind to explain a bit the logic behind in small pieces? I am not sure I understand how you use "~". Thank you a lot!